# Why does Java think my object is a variable?

Tags: java, variables, object

Ok so I'm trying to make a simple pong game. I have a paddle that follows the mouse and a ball that bounces around. I wrote a method `collidesWith(Sprite s)` inside of my Sprite class that checks if the ball collides with the paddle (this works and isn't the problem). I have two objects extending my sprite class, a ball and a paddle object. So inside of my ball class I'm trying to check if it collides with the paddle. So I've tried

```
if(this.collidesWith(paddle) == true){
    System.out.println("They touched");
}
```

I've also tried `ball.collidesWith(paddle)` and other combinations but it always says the same thing about the paddle (and the ball when I use `ball.collidesWith`) `"Cannot find symbol. Symbol: variable paddle(or ball). Location: class Ball"`

So if I'm reading this right, it thinks that the paddle (and ball) are variables and it's complaining because it can't find them. How can I make it understand I am passing in objects, not variables?

For extra information, an earlier assignment had me make two boxes and for them to change colors when they were colliding. In that assignment I used very similar code to above with

```
if(boxOne.collidesWith(boxTwo) == true){
      System.out.println("yes");
}
```

And in this code it worked just fine. The program knew that boxOne and boxTwo were child classes of my Sprite class. Anyone know why they wouldn't work the same?

Comment: Do you have an instance of a Paddle variable called paddle? And is this class a Ball class? Object == Variable

Comment: `== true`? NO NO NO NO NO

Comment: It might help to include a the surrounding code for both examples (not the whole thing - but enough, see http://sscce.org ) - you may realize the problem while doing this.

Comment: Show the source for the fields of each class

Comment: @Kevin Reminds me of the early days... Anyway user2896898 you do not need the == true part.

Comment: Yes I do have an instance of Paddle called paddle. And yeah this is inside the Ball class. So atm the closest I have to working is the this.collidesWith(paddle) one because the 'this' works obviously but for some reason it isn't seeing the paddle class. I tried super.paddle (I'm new to programming and figured maybe I needed to go up the tree to Sprite before going back down to paddle) but that didn't work either.

Comment: Variables are references to objects (except when they're primitives). This is a scoping or naming issue. No clue what "going up the tree to Sprite before going back down" means without context.

Comment: Unless you applied the @Override annotation to the collidesWith() method and changed it in your paddle class, this.collidesWith() is the same as super.collidesWith().

Comment: <sarcasm biting="True">Yes, among all the issues at play in this question, the most significant is that OP redundantly tests the truth of a boolean value.</sarcasm>

Comment: Are you using an IDE such as Eclipse or Netbeans? They will help you find these kind of problems easier.

Answer (score 3):

```
class Paddle {}
```

`Paddle` is a class.

```
Paddle paddle;
```

`paddle` is a variable which doesn't yet refer to an instance of the `Paddle` class (aka an object).

```
Paddle paddle = new Paddle();
```

This `paddle` is a variable and refers to an instance of `Paddle`.

```
ball.collidesWith(paddle)
```

is an expression that invokes the method named `collidesWith` on the object referred to by the variable named `ball` and passes it the object referred to by the variable named `paddle`. If you haven't defined a variable named `ball` and a variable named `paddle` in the same or an enclosing lexical scope of this expression, then the expression isn't valid. If you've created variables `ball` and `paddle` but haven't set them to refer to some instance, then the expression will compile but won't execute correctly. You should have something like this:

```
Ball ball = new Ball();
Paddle paddle = new Paddle();
if (ball.collidesWith(paddle)) { ... }
```

Or if, as you indicated, you're inside the Ball class, you may have something like:

```
class Ball {
    boolean collidesWith(Paddle paddle) {
        ...
    }

    void somethingElseWithAPaddle(Paddle paddle) {
        if (this.collidesWith(paddle)) { ... }
    }
}
```

In that case, `this` is a variable that you don't have to define and refers to the object on which the method was invoked. Wherever you write the expression, `paddle` has to be a variable that's declared somewhere visible.

Comment: 'Same *or an enclosing* lexical scope', otherwise +1.

Comment: @EJP: It made sense in my head when I wrote it. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

My guess (as with the limited information you're giving I can't do much more than guess): you did not declare the `paddle` in a scope that the ball class knows. Or maybe you did declare it, but it is not defined at the time this code runs.

Normally, you'll write a managing class that knows of and maintains the paddle instances and at the same time knows the ball instance. Instead of having the ball check for collisions, you'd make your managing class do this instead. Considering the managing class would also be responsible for building your paddles and ball, it would already have them in the right scope. Your managing class would have a `ball.collidesWith(paddle)` check for each of the two paddles.